# Find all files starting with F

Tags: android, filter, file-type, samsung

I use Samsung Myfiles to bring up .pdf files of music. I need to get them on the screen quickly. With Windows Explorer I could tap one letter key and it would take me to the first filename starting with that letter.

What is the best Myfiles can do to emulate that?

I tried the Search with Filters. It could restrict me to the folder and file type I wanted, but that seems to be all.

I'm not interested in writing code, just using standard features. I don't think Samsung supports COBOL anyway!